# How to get Volume ID of a hard drive by given letter in Python on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, winapi, wmi

I need a way to obtain volume id of a hard drive that looks like `xxxx-xxxx` (for example A78B-12BF) on Windows in Python 3.

```
drive_letter = "H:"
volume_id = get_volume_id(drive_letter)  # <--- what should be here?
print(volume_id)  # A78B-12BF
```

Comment: The VSN is `os.stat(drive_letter).st_dev`. To format it like you want, you can use `'{:04X}-{:04X}'.format(vsn >> 16, vsn & 0xffff)`.

Comment: But this is technically not a unique ID in Windows. By Microsoft's specs the volume serial number doesn't even have to be non-zero. For example, it's 0 for a WebDAV drive.

Comment: I don't know if Python has a wrapper for this, but the native Win32 way to get a volume ID of a drive is [`GetVolumeInformation()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364993.aspx)

Comment: @RemyLebeau, `os.stat` calls `GetFileInformationByHandle` and uses `dwVolumeSerialNumber` as the `st_dev` value. This is a common choice, but technically it's bogus. The VSN does not uniquely identify a volume device on Windows.